# backbone.bootstrapModal separate events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

Can I separate the callback events in a backbone.BootstrapModal?

Saying for example that i want the cancel button to act like a logout button, the ok one will be the login while the close (right hand side, at the top) just close the modal?

I've been searching for this but i wasn't able to find anything...
This is the documentation but I didn't find anything usefull regarding what i need

https://github.com/powmedia/backbone.bootstrap-modal

Basically it needs to call a function on close and another, different, on cancel...

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, at the end I decided to hide the default cancel button and create a custom one with the event I wanted trigger by this new one.

Thanks anyway